# Soccer winning probabilies from ELO strength indicator

Tags: python

What can I do to improve this function, which calculates the [win expectancy](http://www.eloratings.net/system.html) of a soccer team, given their strength:

```
def winning_prob(first, second, first_at_home=False, second_at_home=False):
    """ Return winning probability, given ELO ratings of two soccer teams 

    Args:
        first: ELO rating of first team
        second: ELO rating of second team
        first_at_home: is first team playing at home?
        second_at_home: is second team playing at home?

    Returns:
        Winning probability of first team against second team
    """
    if first_at_home:
        first = first + 100
    if second_at_home:
        second = second + 100

    difference = (first - second) / 400.0
    return 1.0 / (10**(-difference) + 1.0)
```

Especially the two boolean switches look clunky to me, but the explanation is simpler that way. What improvements do you see?

Comment: Are `first_at_home` and `second_at_home` mutually exclusive?

Comment: Usually yes, but there are teams that share the same city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the possibility of `first_at_home` and `second_at_home` both being `True`, there really is not too much to improve on here.

The only things I see are:

1. Instead of doing `first = first + 100`, you can do `first += 100`.
2. Instead of doing `-((first - second)/ 400.0)` you can do `(second - first)/ 400.0`.
3. There is also no need to specify your operands as floats (`400.0` vs `400`) because Python does float division with the basic `/` operator.

Here are my improvements:

```
def winning_prob(first, second, first_at_home=False, second_at_home=False):
    """ Return winning probability, given ELO ratings of two soccer teams 

    Args:
        first: ELO rating of first team
        second: ELO rating of second team
        first_at_home: is first team playing at home?
        second_at_home: is second team playing at home?

    Returns:
        Winning probability of first team against second team
    """
    if first_at_home:
        first += 100
    if second_at_home:
        second += 100

    return 1 / (10**((second - first)/400) + 1)
```

Comment: `/` behaviour actually depends on the version: `1/3` equals `0.333..` in Python 3.x, while it is `0` in Python 2.7. Maybe I sprinkled the `.0` to generously, but AFAIK one decimal point is required somewhere to ensure that it works for both versions.

Comment: [PEP 238 -- Changing the divison operator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) summarizes the situation. Under Pyton 2, one can use `from __future__ import division` to get the Python 3 behaviour.